# Kernel Thread that won't exit, Load Average +1

Tags: linux, kernel, nfs, threads, cpu-load

So I have a new server that is up and running with Centos 6, and the load average is stuck hovering around 1, even when the machine is nearly idle.  I reviewed the process table and found this running:

```
root@myserver:~]# ps -efl|grep " [D] "
1 D root     43252     2  0  80   0 -     0 rpc_wa Apr01 ?        00:00:00 [10.125.50.56-ma]
```

The timing (Apr01) lines up perfectly with my trending graphs, and it was right around the time I was working with mounting an NFS share from that IP address.  However, the thread is in uninterruptible sleep, and I don't know how to get rid of it.  I have unmounted any/all NFS mounts I had, and it still won't go away.

Does anyone know what this process/thread is, and if there is a way to help it exit without restarting the box?  It is already in production so I'd really like to avoid that.

Comment: The `D` flag (2nd column) says that it's in uninterruptable sleep and I think you can't kill that with `-9`. You can try `-SEGV`. And you can try to find out the exact `WCHAN`, `rpc_wa` is just the beginning of it.

Answer (score -1):

If it's ok just to kill the thread, you can try to use command

```
kill -9 43252
```

It will send `SIGKILL` signal to the process, which should immediately terminate it.

Comment: I think you missed that the process is in an uninterruptible sleep, so interrupting it isn't an option.